# Структура Базы данных товаров

Tags: sql, база-данных

имеются товары разных категорий, например смартфон, телевизор, велосипед, еда какая-нибудь. У них есть одни и те же свойства (названия, описание и т.д). Как создать структуру БД? Имеется несколько предположений:

1. Для каждой сущности создать отдельную таблицу. Но как тогда определить для них единый id, чтобы бы по Id можно было сразу определить, что за товар. К тому же дублирование будет
2. Создать общую таблицу product, в которой будут храниться общие свойства и тип продукта. различаемые свойства хранятся в отдельных таблицах сущностей.
3. Создать одну таблицу, в которой хранятся все свойства. Отсутствующие свойства имеют значения null, а выборка будет осуществлять только тех свойств, которые присущи этой сущности. По мере добавления новых категорий товаров, добавляются и новые свойства в таблицу

Посоветуйте, как лучше поступить, и аргументируйте свой совет.
Также возможно вы посоветуете другие способы.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1 - мне нравится меньше всего.
Варианты 2 и 3 - более-менее одинаковые, 3 хорош тем, что можно использовать один и тот же запрос везде, просто при формировании конкретной страницы уже на клиенте выбирать, какие поля брать, какие нет. А в варианте 2 можно не тащить кучу лишних полей, но придется делать второй запрос.

Есть еще такая штука, как [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). Штука в принципе неплохая, если не увлекаться ей очень сильно. Идея, если вкратце, заключается в том, что вы создаете таблицы значений (по одной на каждый тип данных), и таблицу свойств. Например, в таблицу "свойства" вставляете значение "длина", а в таблицу "значения" - значение "100". И связываете все это между собой. Соответственно, у вас на каждый объект будет столько строк со свойствами, сколько самих свойств. Можно объединить это с вариантом 2, когда общие свойства хранятся в одной таблице, а остальные - в EAV.

Comment: Взял пример с википедии:
(<пациент XYZ, 1/5/98 9:30 утра>, <температура в градусах по Фаренгейту>, "102")
(<пациент XYZ, 1/5/98 9:30 утра>, <Присутствие кашля>, "Истина")
(<пациент XYZ, 1/5/98 9:30 утра>, <тип кашля>, "с мокротой, желтоватый, полоска крови")
(<пациент XYZ, 1/5/98 9:30 утра>, <частота сердечных сокращений в ударах в минуту>, "98") Это данные для одного товара допустим. Чтобы добавлять записи для другого товара мне придется копировать все поля в столбце 2 (у второго же тоже есть давление, количество ударов в минуту) и изменять значения в 3 столбце.

Comment: Я думаю это дублирование информации. Да выборка будет очень хорошая. Достаточно выбрать все значения где значение в 1 столбце равна некоторому значению. Но если допустим мне забрать данные всех товаров 1 категории то как осуществить выборку? По общей таблицы, где будет храниться тип товара( в данном случае пациент?

Answer (score 0):

1 вариант приведет к тому, что в базе возникнет излишне много таблиц, так как категорий товаров огромное число. Из двух других вариантов я бы выбрал под номером 2, потому что более чистая и расширяемая структура. Она спасет, если понадобится получить только инфу конкретной категории товара, например. В 3 кейсе вы не сможете этого сделать, если не держите в голове или где-то под рукой список что к чему относится (ведь поля могут быть не заполнены не потому, что продукт не относится к определенной категории, а просто не было полных данных на момент внесения записи).

Comment: "Она спасет, если понадобится получить только инфу конкретной категории товара, например....." Но ведь во 2 варианте мне все равно придется выбирать сначала данные из общей таблицы и потом данные из конкретной категории товара. Я думаю этот вариант не лучше чем вариант номер 3. Почему я так говорю: Например есть смартфоны и планшенты. Каких свойств нету у одного и есть у другого? Почти никаких. Но во втором результате мне придется создавать отдельную таблицу как и под смартфоны, так и под планшеты, у которых свойства одинаковы.

Comment: Почему мне эти свойсва не засунуть в таблицу общих? Потому что, в базе данных могут быть данные о велосипеде, у которых не может быть таких свойств. Следовательно я не могу закидывать большинство общих свойств и мне придется во 2 варианте дублировать информацию. А по поводу данных, которых нет на момент записи, ну и что, я просто выведу неизвестно или вообще не выведу. Как по мне именно 3 вариант наиболее оптимальный. Да увеличивается сложность запроса из-за необходимости выбора только определенных полей из таблицы для каждой сущности, но у меня и дублирование данных уменьшается.

Comment: @danilshik, а если сделать таблицу "mobile devices" и связь многие-ко-многим, которая связана и с телефонами, и с планшетами?

Comment: А если мне нужно добавить данные обычных кнопочных телефонов? У них есть некоторые свойства Mobile devices, но также многих и нет. И куда мне их добавлять?В таблицу Mobile devices и многие параметры делать значение null? Или заводить отдельную таблицу? (Но тогда идет дублирование данных, ведь у него же все таки есть похожие свойства). Поэтому я думаю 3 наиболее оптимальный. Нам не приходится плодить большое количество таблиц, все можно писать в 1, ненужные свойства или неизвестные значения свойств делать значение Null, а выбирать только нужные поняли для сущности

Comment: Мне кажется, что количество полей таблицы может сильно разрастись, и это скажется на производительности работы с ней при большом количестве записей и сложных выборках.

Comment: В этом вы правы

Comment: Что же подождем других комментарий, так как количество таблиц во втором варинте почти соответствует количеству таблиц в 1 варианте.

Comment: Вопрос: допустим я выбрал данные о продукте(смартфон) из общей таблицы (поле тип продукта), как мне забрать данные из сущности смартфона? Ведь я не знаю значение этого поля? или придется делать 2 запроса?

Comment: Через JOIN по ключу idПродукта-idCмартфона

Comment: а если нужно idПродукта - idВелосипед. Я же не знаю какая это таблица. А с помощью этой связи описываются связь между двумя таблицами, а не между несколькими